# How to use TCP in Node to interact with other applications

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x, sockets, socket.io

I am new to sockets and I want to connect two processes (only on localhost). I have my python program which does something and needs to send it's results permanently to an user interface written in javascript. I considered Socket.IO but as far as I know Socket.IO lies on top of http and python sockets are TCP connections. Is it even possible to connect javascript and python via sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Net` Module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/net.html) that comes with the Node.js Core API to create a TCP Socket Server or to connect to an existing TCP server as a Client.

If you're looking to create a new TCP Server you can use [`net.createServer()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) or create a `new Server` yourself.

```
const {Server} = require('net')

const server = new Server(socket=> {
  console.log('client connected')

  // Attach listeners for the socket
  socket.on('data', message => {
    console.log('message')

    // Write back to the client
    socket.write('world')     
  })

  // Send the client a message to disconnect from the server after a minute
  setTimeout(() => socket.write('disconnect'), 60000)

  socket.on('end', () => console.log('client disconnected'))
})

server.listen('localhost', () => console.log('listening'))
```

If you're looking to create a client TCP connection to an existing server you can use [`net.createConnection()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection) or create a [`new Socket`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket)  and connect to the TCP server using [`socket.connect()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_options_connectlistener).

```
const {Socket} = require('net')

const client= new Socket()

client.connect('localhost', () => {
  console.log('connected to localhost')

  client.on('data', message => {
    if (message === 'disconnect') {
      console.log('disconnecting from localhost')
      client.end()
    } else {
      console.log(`Message from the Server: ${message}`)
    }
  })

  client.write('hello!')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know about a project that used the [ZeroMQ messaging protocol](http://davekuhlman.org/zeromq-python-nodejs.html) to do exactly what you're interested in. You should consider taking a look at that.

Answer (score -1):

You can consider a WebSocket although it might be a heavy choice for something solely local.  Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Also, it seems like you are using socket.io, maybe you should try this library: https://github.com/evanw/socket.io-python which seems to do something related to your project.